# What is meant by the "data" and "analytics" in a RowKey of a CapacityEntity

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using a `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Analytics.CloudAnalyticsClient` to get the Blob Capacity of a Storage Account using the following code:

```
string StorageAccountName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountName"];
string StorageAccountKey = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountKey"];
StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey);
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);

var client = account.CreateCloudAnalyticsClient();
var result = client.CreateCapacityQuery().Execute();`
```

When I do this, result returns an `IEnumerable<CapacityEntity>`. While this works fine, I see that I get 2 values in the list for each day (since a new `$MetricsCapacityBlob` is put in each day), where the main difference is that one has a `RowKey` property of `"data"`, while the other has a RowKey property of `"analytics"`.

I would like to know what the difference between these two are and if I should simply just add the both of them to get the total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Storage Analytics Metrics Table Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343264.aspx) document should cover everything you need to know.

Here is how it describes the RowKey property:

> Indicates whether the capacity table entity applies to user data or
>   Storage Analytics data, in the following format: < data|analytics>. If
>   the value is data, this table entity indicates capacity metrics for
>   user data only. If the value is analytics, this table entity indicates
>   capacity metrics for Storage Analytics data only, specifically the
>   capacity consumed by the $logs blob container.

Comment: Thanks, I've put in the relevant text into the answer in case the link stops working at some point in the future.